# vue: how to make the object passed to component reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/PayPVp?editors=1010)

I have a component which has an `location` object as `props`. The argument I passed in is `locations[index]` which is a selected item from a `locations` array.

However, the component cannot react when the `index` change. As you can see in the demo, the JSON change as you click the button, but the component cannot update.

What's the best way to make the component reactive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `location` component populates the `province` and `city` data properties in the `mounted` hook only. When the `location` prop changes, the `mounted` hook will not be called again, so you are left with stale data.

Use a computed property instead:

```es6
computed: {
  province() {
    return this.location.province;
  },
  city() {
    return this.location.city;
  }
}
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKBPGo?editors=1010)

If you really do require `province` and `city` to be data properties (and not computed properties) then you will need to watch the `location` prop to update the properties:

```es6
data() {
  return {
    province: null,
    city: null
  }
},
watch: {
  location: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(loc) {
      this.province = loc.province;
      this.city = loc.city;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just bind to location.province. No need for computed properties or watchers.

Comment: @FINDarkside I don't think that is true. In my case the property is not updated when binding directly... Initially the data is populated by an empty value in the child component, and when updating location.province in the parent it won't be reflected in the child... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Decade Moon If I don't have an object being passed as a property but just a value:
like `<Location :province="location.province" />` and I want the province value to be changed within the child (`Location`) component, I think computed properties do not work either. Is that correct? Event watching it does not help...

Can I somehow make props of a primitive type reactive?

Comment: @Merc If you are passing a primitive value down through a prop, it cannot be updated directly by the child. The only way for the child to "update" it is to emit an event to the parent (`this.$emit('update:province', value)`) so the parent can update it. This is explained in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier).

Comment: @DecadeMoon I do know about that, but I want it to be the other way around. The parent passes an initial prop (primitive) to a child, and then gets it's value updated. It should then inform the child and that one should update that primitive. So it's really the question written in the title but in my case I have primitives...

Comment: @Merc The behavior you describe should already work out of the box; if it isn't then you have not declared the `location.province` property upfront on the object and it isn't reactive. Does it update if you change the value using [`Vue.set`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)?

Comment: Hi @DecadeMoon. Due to the limited options of describing my problem in this comment here I made another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286288/vue-how-to-make-primitive-prop-reactive-should-update-on-change-within-parent
Maybe you could have a look at it there? :) Thx

Comment: @DecadeMoon, thanks. Watcher worked for me like a charm since I always receive an object in the prop.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats states that if the object attribute is not yet defined, Vue will not detect when the attribute is created.  Vue. set on the component receiving props doesn't help either. Bit of a bummer given that objects and reactivity should be intrinsic to Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Nested items in your prop `location` won't be reactive, you'll need to use something like [lodash deepClone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) :

```
<location :location.sync="_.deepClone(loc)"></location>
```

That's it, no need for watchers or anything else.