# Vue: How to make primitive prop reactive (should update on change within parent component)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I started a little discussion within [this post: vue: how to make the object passed to component reactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054508/vue-how-to-make-the-object-passed-to-component-reactive) in the comments section.

(Thx to @DecadeMoon who tried to help me out there...)

Due to the limited options in a comment-field I am starting a new thread here:

**Problem**
I have a form that has some empty input fields on load. The form sets a filter for a UI. The filters parameters are «saved» in the URL, which allows sharing a certain filter setting.

`domain.com?filter1=value1&filter2=value2`

So on load I check if there are any query parameters present and if so I save them to my vuex store. Multiple components watch the vuex store to update their UI. So does the filter itself, so does a data-table with actual filtered items.

My problem is, that my input fields need to be «filled» with values from the url.

So I have the following information pathway:

```
 1. filter is initiated with empty fields
 2. Check url params
 3. save url filter to vuex store
 4. parent component (form) receives set filter
 5. parent component should update it's child (input field)
```

But let me share some code to illustrate this more:

```
// FilterForm.vue

...
props: {
    fields: {
    //  contain also the information about the value of a field
    // is being passed down as a prop of its parent, which watches the vuex store
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
...
</script>

<template>
...
<template v-for="(field, index) in fields">
<FormFieldText
  if="field.type === 'text'"
  :key="index"
  v-model="formData[field.name]"
  :value="field.value" <------------
/>
...
```

In my vue inspector I can see that the data within FormFieldText is updated:
[image]
[image]
(first of course this value is empty, and then the url value is passed down until here.)

Now because `field.value` is bound within the template:
`:value="field.value"` I would expect that the value of the child is updated whenever `field.value` (String) changes.

[image]

This is not the case.

```
// FormFieldText.vue

export default {
  name: 'FormFieldText',
  props: {
    value: { <------------
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: '',
    },
...
</script>

<template>
  ...
      <input
        type="text"
        :value="value" <------------
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      />
    </label>
...
</template>
```

I also tried to watch the `value`, but this watcher is never executed either.

```
watch: {
    value: {
      handler(newValue) {
        console.log('newValue: ', newValue)
      },
    },
  },
```

So how could I achieve the following:

1. Parent initiates a child with an empty value
2. Parent receives from its own parent an update of the data
3. Parent should pass this information on to child
4. Child should update its UI (showing the value in the input field).

I hope I got my problem more or less clear. If anything remains unclear, I would be happy to clarify further.

Thanks for any input.
Cheers

Comment: check `.sync` and `$emit('update:[propname]', newValue)`

Comment: Why are you binding to `value` and `v-model` (to two different values nonetheless)? `v-model` already binds to `value` and takes precedence over your `:value` binding.

Comment: @Estradiaz as far as I know sync is automatically making sure that the value in the parent and within the child stay the same. In my case I need a _local_ state for the child, but whenever a value from the parent arrives, it should override it. So I guess sync is not gonna work?!

Comment: @DecadeMoon that is very true. I had only the `v-model` and then realized that I needed to propagate changed `values` to the child so I added `:value`. Thanks for the hint. Maybe this leads me somewhere...

Comment: ok then i missunderstood you - use a watcher and a local variable then -> watcher immediate true -> overridelocal var everytime, also possible with computed not sure the pattern name though - some proxy style pattern

Comment: @Estradiaz I did try that, by using a local data var that is overridden., but as I said the watcher is not even triggered (only the first time; due to `immediate`), but after that I don't see any changes there...

Comment: hmm wait there is a collision between v-model and value isnt there? can you try rename it

Comment: It is. Thanks @Estradiaz & @Decade Moon
I figured it out now. I first had this collision. The underlying problem is here though: I have a prop passed into the filter (parent) called `fields`. This object contains changes if there are url params set. I had a `v-model`  binding for `formData[field.name]`. So whenever `fields` change the value won't appear in formData. I now went for `:value="field.value" & @input="updateFormData($event, field.name)"` By that I can guarantee that the values within `fields` are passed down and when the input emits its value up, I save this into formData.